# Optional year/month/day in Django model date field(s)

Tags: python, django, datetime, date, django-models

I want a Django model to have a date field in which the year, month, and day are all optional.  An example value could be as generic as `2008` or as specific as `May 10, 2008`. Is it possible to define a `DateField` to behave this way? Or am I better off defining year/month/day as separate integers, like this?

```
model Book(models.Model):
    publication_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    publication_month = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    publication_day = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Is "May 10" a valid date for your needs?

Comment: Yes--each value (year, month, day) is optional.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The django-date-extensions at https://github.com/dracos/django-date-extensions (by me, for exactly for this purpose) includes an ApproximateDate object to handle dates that might not have a month or a day.

Answer (score 2):

The Django class DateTimeField is based on the python datetime.datetime class where year, month and day are mandatory:

```
datetime.datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[, tzinfo]]]]])
```

In your place, instead of defining three integer fields I would use the Django DateTimeField and and a boolean which tels me if I should take only the year or the whole date.